# Custom scrollbar arrows

Tags: java, image, swing, custom-component, jscrollbar

Im am trying to customize a jScrollPane using the code below. It works, It changes the color the way I want it, but hides the arrowbuttons.

What I want is to make them visible again and change them with a custom image. I tried searching on this forum, but I couldnt find any info about it.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

```
    private Image imageThumb, imageTrack;
    private JButton b = new JButton() {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(0, 0);
        }
    };

  public YourScrollbarUI () {
        imageThumb = WrapImage .create(45, 45, new Color(46,218,163));
        imageTrack = WrapImage .create(32, 32, new Color(90,90,90));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintThumb(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle r) {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        ((Graphics2D) g).drawImage(imageThumb,
                r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintTrack(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle r) {
        ((Graphics2D) g).drawImage(imageTrack,
                r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected JButton createDecreaseButton(int orientation) {
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    protected JButton createIncreaseButton(int orientation) {
        return b;
    }

private static class WrapImage {

    static public Image create(int w, int h, Color c) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
        g2d.setPaint(c);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g2d.dispose();
        return bi;}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It changes the color the way I want it, but hides the arrowbuttons.

Here is the problem:

```
private JButton b = new JButton() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(0, 0); // why (0,0) ???
    }
};
```

In your code `b` button is the responsible for painting the arrows through `createDecreaseButton` and `createIncreaseButton` methods. If its preferred size is `(0,0)` then logically it won't be visible.

> What I want is to make them visible again and change them with a
>   custom image.

You need to modify `createDecreaseButton` and `createIncreaseButton` to make them return a new `JButton` with the desired icon.

**Update**

> I already tried playing with the prefferedsize (making them the same
>   size as the custom image), but the custom arrowimages are still not
>   showing up. Im clueless

Look at this working example. `MyScrollbarUI` extends from [BasicScrollBarUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicScrollBarUI.html) just as your class does. You'll see the key is overrding the button's `getPreferredSize()` method and setting the appropriate icon as needed.

In this regard I should say [BasicScrollBarUI.createDecreaseButton(int orientation)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicScrollBarUI.html#createDecreaseButton%28int%29) and [BasicScrollBarUI.createIncreaseButton(int orientation)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicScrollBarUI.html#createIncreaseButton%28int%29) methods are poorly documented (there's no javadoc). But if you dive into this class using an IDE then you'll see `orientation` paramenter can take one of these values: `SwingConstants.NORTH, SwingConstants.SOUTH, SwingConstants.EAST, SwingConstants.WEST`. Keep this in mind when look at `getAppropriateIcon(int orientation)` method.

These are used icons: [image: Up arrow][image: Down arrow][image: Left arrow][image: Right arrow]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI;

public class Demo {

    private void initGUI(){
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(10, 20));
        scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setUI(new MyScrollbarUI());
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new MyScrollbarUI());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Demo().initGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    class MyScrollbarUI extends BasicScrollBarUI {

        private ImageIcon downArrow, upArrow, leftArrow, rightArrow;

        public MyScrollbarUI(){
            try {
                upArrow = new ImageIcon(new java.net.URL("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/16/Actions-arrow-up-icon.png"));
                downArrow = new ImageIcon(new java.net.URL("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/16/Actions-arrow-down-icon.png"));
                rightArrow = new ImageIcon(new java.net.URL("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/16/Actions-arrow-right-icon.png"));
                leftArrow = new ImageIcon(new java.net.URL("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/16/Actions-arrow-left-icon.png"));
            } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }        
        }

        @Override
        protected JButton createDecreaseButton(int orientation) {
            JButton decreaseButton = new JButton(getAppropriateIcon(orientation)){
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(22, 22);
                }
            };
            return decreaseButton;
        }

        @Override
        protected JButton createIncreaseButton(int orientation) {
            JButton increaseButton = new JButton(getAppropriateIcon(orientation)){
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(22, 22);
                }
            };
            return increaseButton;
        }

        private ImageIcon getAppropriateIcon(int orientation){
            switch(orientation){
                case SwingConstants.SOUTH: return downArrow;
                case SwingConstants.NORTH: return upArrow;
                case SwingConstants.EAST: return rightArrow;
                    default: return leftArrow;
            }
        }
    }    

}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: I tried your code by modifying the createDecreaseButton and createIncreaseButton, but the custom icon is not showing up. Instead it is showing up a small portion of (what I think it is) a standard Jbutton. How can we fix this?

Comment: @RichardAvalos You can play around overriding getPreferredSize method (you already did but returning `(0,0)` which made button not visible). See updated answer. It's just an example. You surely can do it better.

Comment: Srry for the late response. I already tried playing with the prefferedsize (making them the same size as the custom image), but the custom arrowimages are still not showing up. Im clueless

Comment: @RichardAvalos please see updated answer. Hope it be helpful :)