# Disable scrollbar thumb under semi transparent layer

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, scrollbar, transparent

so this is my situation. I have a jscrollpane with some components in them. 
After pushing a button a semi transparent jpanel shows up covering my jscrollpane.
When I hover my mouse over the components or scrollbar, they show up again (as if they have come on top of the semi transparent layer, instead of staying underneath it).

I fixed the components part by disabling them with this code.

```
Component[] com = jPanel2.getComponents();
        for (int a = 0; a < com.length; a++) {
            com[a].setEnabled(false);
        }
```

The problem I still have is that the thumb of my scrollbar still shows up when I hover over it. I think I need to disable the thumb of my scrollbar.

Can anyone help me with this?

I've added the code(method) I use for the transparentlayer.

Transparentlayer

```
public class TransparentPanel extends JPanel {
{
    setOpaque(false);
}
/**
 *
 * @param g
 */
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(getBackground());
    Rectangle r = g.getClipBounds();
    g.fillRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Comment: Try calling super.paintComponent first, it is responsible for preparing the grapcs context for painting, which is very important, but especially important when you are using a transparent component

Comment: hmz, didnt work unfortunately. Any other options I can try?

Comment: *After pushing a button a semi transparent jpanel shows up covering my jscrollpane.* How do you do that? I think it's relevant to your problem and you should add the code in your question. Or even better post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) *P.S.:* I see your "arrows" still don't show, as you ignore [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577893/custom-scrollbar-arrows/19589440#19589440)

Comment: @dic19, I put my jscrollpane into a jpanel and made my transparentpanel appear above the jpanel. I can post a short and working example of it in a zip file. Since i've made it in the netbeans GUI designer I dont know how to convert it into pure code :/ (srry im just a beginning programmer). Can someone please let me know if this is a correct way of posting an SSCCE?

Comment: I've also noticed that the custom scrollbar has nothing to do with this. I have edited my question above.